# How to identify local maxima of FFT data

Tags: python, audio, signal-processing, fft

I'm working on analysis of audio files in Python, specifically music audio, and I've applied the DFT (FFT) to get data in the frequency domain, but no amount of searching or fiddling around with it has revealed a good way to identify "peaks"/local maxima in the frequencies. My data is pretty noisy, an example of the graph after applying the Fourier Transform is below. Help would be really appreciated. I'm also looking at retrieving MFCC coefficients from this data, but I'm also not sure how to go about doing that, so knowledge on that subject would also be useful.

[image: FFT of Audio File]

Comment: I would simply do a running average with appropriate width (10Hz seems like a good start) to smooth your data then just look for local max on the  denoised signal...

Comment: try with this library: https://github.com/jameslyons/python_speech_features, "don't repeat yourself", "Do not reinvent the wheel"

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to smooth your (fft) data by running a low pass filtering. After that, you can find zero crossings on the gradients of signal. You can filter the signal with [-1, 1] to find the gradient, and pick the elements whose predecessor is positive and successor is negative.